# How to get from float 0.01 to 0.009

Tags: python

I want to make a code that takes a number like `0.001` and returns me `0.0009` so always one decimal place lower. But this should also work with for example `0.005` so that i get `0.004` is there a way to do this? Also I get my numbers as a string so is there a way to convert it without having to deal with sientific notation.

Comment: well, you could do the "ugly" way by removing the last char of the string, if it's a one, you add 09 to the string, and otherwise you just substract 1 to it and reput it in the string

Comment: Can the input ever look like "0.0010"? How about "0.012"? "1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```py
f = lambda x:float(x[:-1]+'09') if x[-1]=='1' else float(x[:-1]+str(int(x[-1])-1))

print(f('0.001'))
print(f('0.004'))
```

Output:

```
0.0009
0.003
```

Answer (score 1):

if you would rather avoid the issues with internal number representations, here's a long winded way of doing this.

```
number = "0.005"
# number = "0.1"

def return_a_lower_decimal(number):
    last_digit = number[-1:]
    num_digits = len(number)
    decimal_filler = "0"*(num_digits-3)
    if last_digit != "1":
        new_number = "0." + decimal_filler + str(int(last_digit)-1)
    else:
        new_number = "0.0" + decimal_filler + "9"    
    return(new_number)    

print(return_a_lower_decimal(number))

# assumptions - all numbers offered are strings of the form "0.000....d", where d is a single non-zero digit
```

Answer (score 1):

since you said you get your data in strings

```
a="0.0009"
b={"1":"09","2":"1","9":"8","8":"7","7":"6","7":"6","6":"5","5":"4","4":"3","3":"2"}
a=a[:-1]+b[a[-1]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
How would you make that to get one more not one less.

Comment: if all your input values are less than 0.9 then if a[-1] is 9 take last two values; and a new map with reversed key,value pairs;

Comment: No i mean instead of getting from 0.05 to 0.04 what do i need to change in the code to get from 0.05 to 0.06?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```py
>>> def converter(num):
...     if int(str(num).replace(".", "")) == 1:
...         return num * 9 / 10
...     else:
...         return float(str(num)[:-1] + str(int(str(num)[-1]) - 1))
...
```

output:

```py
>>> converter(0.001)
0.0009000000000000001
>>> converter(0.005)
0.004
```

what we are doing is checking that if the number is some sort of 0.000...01 type in if condition if it is we are multiplying it with 9/10 to get desired result.

while in other cases we are simply extracting last digit reducing it by 1 and recombining the whole.

so it is actually working but we got `0.0009000000000000001` instead of `0.0009` its because internal representation of calculated result, not programs fault.